# Flutter, how to make a Listview.builder anchored to the bottom

Tags: flutter

How do I make the `ListView.builder` start with a bottom anchor on my `Container`?

[image: pict]

Comment: Provide more explanation or a visual sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many ways to understand this sentence. Here is a random pick on what it could mean:

[image]

Is this what you are looking for?

You can achieve this by using an `alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter` on your `Container` and `reverse: true` on the `ListView`.

### Full source code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.amber.shade300,
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: ListTile(title: Text('Tile $index')),
          ),
          itemCount: 6,
          reverse: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that was it ty!

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Adding just `reverse: true` to my listview builder was enough.

**Full Code**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(
        MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          home: HomePage(),
        ),
      );
    }
    
    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: ListTile(title: Text('Tile $index')),
                ),
                itemCount: 6,
                reverse: true, //Adding just this was enough in my case
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```